# The next step after Java Play Framework 1.2.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, grails, frameworks, playframework

I am wondering what's the next logical step after developing applications with java play framework?

I really love to develop with play 1.2 but I am inconfident about its future, the main developers stopped their support on it (yet it is still opensource) and play 2.0 is a completely different product.

I tried to study play 2.0, but I just couldn't like the scala language (although it sounds like a great language to code)

So I decided to focus my web application projects to another framework. It shouldn't have to be java, but I prefer it to be a platform independent framework like ruby, or else. (I am also a .net developer with mcp certificate but i usually use osx enviroment for coding and I'm not a big fan of windows).

My Current problems with the play framework:

1. It works quite well but i dont see a future with it i am afraid the opensource community will stop developing 1.2.x after some time
2. Play 2.0 threads java as a second class citizen, and i am starting to losing my faith to its developers.
3. There are not much people looking for play framework jobs

The framework should be:

1. Platform independent
2. Database independent (can use hibernate
   or else..)
3. Has a large user community
4. Has to be a proven framework with large enterprise applications

I've searched a little bit and I found grails, spring and RoR frameworks.

Ok then to make things clearer, heres a summary about my question:

1. Should i continiue from the "java" path?, i have concerns about time is changing and in few years, there will be more "scala" like functional languages used in web frameworks and they will be more useful in future frameworks
2. I am also wondering about Ruby langugage? Any insights about where will they be in the next 5 years?
3. Where do you see "Play framework with scala/java" in the next 5 years? Will they be worth the time invested on them?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Next step: Play 2.0 with Java, there are only few places where you'll need to learn very basic Scala syntax: templates (simple statements) and configs, (documented)

Comment: If you do not further specify your question according to the FAQ, this question is likely going to be closed. Quote: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." However, your current question is way to broad and based on subjective opinion to fall under that category.

Comment: i've edited my post and wrote about my problems with the current framework, i dont think its a broad question but i hope it is enough for not removing the question.

Comment: For me it is still unclear what is being asked. If it's about web application frameworks in general, this questions is too broad. There is no "THE right framework" for you. However, if you consider rails (probably because you want to learn ruby) but are not sure about performance/scalability etc. compared to e.g. PHP or Django, then this would be a more proper question.

Comment: i have improved my question, howerver, i am asking for opinions from the people who have some experience on open source web frameworks, searching for a framework that is worth for time invested and have a long life span. it doesnt have to be the "one and the right" framework, just i dont want to waste my time for a framework that lasts after few years. So i cannot be specific until i have some more information from people who acutally use it

Answer (score 3):

[**Spring**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

If you know Java then a reasonable thing is to know **Spring** also.

People crap on Spring because they think:

- Its not new and shiny
- You need gallons of XML to do anything.
- Its humongous monolithic beast.

**Besides being mature none of the above is true**. And unlike *Play!* Spring is in it for the long haul.

Spring also doesn't go off and build its "own" of everything but instead relies on best of breed libraries that you plug in. Thus with Spring you can play with what ever templating language, what ever build system, persistence, etc...

Now the only PITA with Spring is finding a good starting point. I recommend either [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) or [MWA](https://github.com/jknack/modern-web-app)

**UPDATE:**

I don't know why I got the -1 when the question was bad anyway (put a comment or something).

He asked for:

> 1. Platform independent
> 2. Database independent (can use hibernate or else..)
> 3. Has a large user community
> 4. Has to be a proven framework with large enterprise applications

IMHO There is not a framework that fits the above points better (particularly enterprise).

**HE asked an opinionated question I gave him one.**

Comment: Thank you, i've also heard those things about spring but i'll keep it in mind.